# Clarification regarding existence in case of Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I was going through the following 2-page handout:

https://stanford.edu/class/msande321/Handouts/Appendix%20B%20-%20Limits%20and%20Expectations.pdf

In Page 2, it is mentioned that if $X_n \geq 0$, by Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT) on Page 1, we can conclude that

$\mathbb{E} \Big[ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n \Big] = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[X_{n}]$.

My question is, is there an implicit assumption on the existence of

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_{n} = X_{\infty}$?

Because MCT on page 1 proves this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

When you are adding non-negative terms then you can only increase the result: thus you can swap $\lim$ with $\lim\sup$ and the latter always exists!

Comment: So to swap the expectations, it is sufficient that $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_{n}$ exists?